# Which sql query is correct

Tags: sql

I have a table A with employees,where id-primary key, boss_id - foreign id. I want to retract employers, who have no employees. Which query is correct?

```
select a1.* 
from A a1 
inner join A a2 on a1.id = a2.boss_id 
where a2.id is null

select a1.* 
from A a1 
left join A a2 on a1.id = a2.boss_id 
where a2.id is null

select a1.* 
from A a1 
inner join A a2 on a1.boss_id = a2.id 
where a2.id is null

select a1.* 
from A a1 
left join A a2 on a1.boss_id = a2.id 
where a2.id is null
```

or every one is incorrect

Comment: What happens when you try them?

Answer (score 1):

Why not direct `not exists`? all recods from `A a1` where `a1` is a boss of no-one:

```
select a1.*
  from A a1 where not exists (select 1 
                                from A a2
                               where a2.boss_id = a1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I renamed your table aliases to make it a little more clear.

```
select boss.* 
from A boss 
left join A emp 
on boss.id = emp.boss_id 
where emp.boss_id is null
```